# Can Boris Johnson prorogue parliament again, after it reconvenes?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, prorogation

Assuming Parliament won't grant on Monday the early general elections that Johnson wants, could he send the Parliament on a much longer vacation using prorogation again? E.g. could he prorogue Parliament until, say, February?

Comment: Yes - but see [this question for legal limits](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/44041/within-what-limits-can-the-prime-minister-ask-the-queen-to-prorogue-parliament), and [this question for practical ones](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41982/if-parliament-were-prorogued-for-a-long-period-how-would-the-government-raise-f).

Comment: Johnson does not prorogue the parliament, he petitions the Queen to prorogue. Still, the Queen does what the elected politicians ask her to do. The Queen prorogued the parliament from *sometime between September 9th and September 12th* until *October 14th*. It would appear quite strange if he petitions the Queen again before *October 14th*, before her next Queen's Speech. This petition needs to be formally delivered to the Queen, the Queen has to grant it, etc., so he couldn't immediately send the parliament home again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Supreme Court has ruled that a prorogation designed to frustrate the function of Parliament is unlawful without justification. Your scenario fits that description.

Comment: The queen cannot refuse to propagate, but under the circumstances, she might be allowed to ask for example one or two of the high court judges for their opinion of the legality of that request - since she followed one request that turned out to be completely illegal.